# Prevent C# from encoding an equal sign

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, asp.net-mvc

- I am working on an AngularJS (i.e. Angular 1) website with an ASP.NET MVC backend.
- I have an anchor tag with `<a href=`.
- The base URL is coming from my `app.config`.
- I need to append parameters to the url, however the equal sign is being encoded as `%3F`.
- I am looking for a simple way to prevent this from happening.

The line in question:

```
<a href="@(System.Web.Configuration.WebConfigurationManager.AppSettings["BaseUrl"] + "?email=test&name=test")">
```

What is the easiest way to force the equal sign to actually show up as an equal sign in the link? Since this is an Angular project I am limited on what C# I can use here.

UPDATE: I don't know why but a forward slash is being inserted between the AppSetting and the query string. Why is that being added and how do I prevent it from being added?

Comment: `System.Web` is not ASP.NET Core (unless you're running ASP.NET Core 2.x on-top of .NET Framework 4.8, which isn't supported anymore), please clarify exactly what you're using.

Comment: Oops, it's framework. Will edit quick.

Comment: Please post the **rendered** HTML, as well as the **raw** value of `BaseUrl` as it appears in your `web.config` (not `app.config`)

Comment: You can try @Html.Raw() method, but make sure you don't compromise your security. Take into consideration no scape at all will happens. Hope it helps or at least give you an idea.